# endless legend no watchtowers

Tags: endless-legend

Second playthrough of Endless Legend...this time using the Westeros map.
I have the imperial highways improvement, but for some reason none of my cities (I have 8) have the ability to make a watchtower.
Kind of a downer since thats the main quest right now (pacify all minor and build a watchtower).

Anyone seen this before?

Comment: I have seen map where literally every single province has a watch tower site on ocean map. Do you have any province bordering ocean tiles?

Answer (score 1):

Since the Westeros map is from the Steam workshop, the map creator probably forgot to add watchtower locations. Either play with a different map from the workshop or use the default map generator.